# Google App Engine Internal Server Error After a Few Minutes

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, twilio, ibm-watson

I'm building an SMS based chatbot using Python, Twilio, Flask, IBM Watson and Google App Engine. It works fine for a few minutes but then inevitably sends up an Internal Response Error.

I've tried editing the yaml file so it has a default expiration of 1 day. It doesn't do anything.

Edit: Currently on automatic scaling,  but I've tried changing from autmatic to basic scaling, and changing min_instances to 1.

Here's the log:

```
2019-07-06 08:57:09 default[20190706t180659]  
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
      response = self.full_dispatch_request()
    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
      rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
      reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
      raise value
    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
      rv = self.dispatch_request()
    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
      return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
    File "/srv/main.py", line 81, in incoming_sms
      r = Watson(b)
    File "/srv/main.py", line 42, in Watson
      input = message_input
    File "/srv/ibm_watson/assistant_v2.py", line 244, in message
      accept_json=True)
    File "/srv/ibm_cloud_sdk_core/base_service.py", line 358, in request
      raise ApiException(response.status_code, error_message, http_response=response)
ibm_cloud_sdk_core.api_exception.ApiException: Error: NotFound: session id 2900da9f-dd77-480a-a939-1a5b060b3f82 for agent instance 6656a86c-ad0e-4463-8344-5f7fdcb4a6fe, Code: 404 , X-global-transaction-id: 5a3699f1cd4e3409e9f89f4fcd87735f
```

**Code to take inputs on Twilio, feed them through Watson and respond.**

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
import os
from twilio import twiml

import ibm_watson

# Set up Assistant service.
service = ibm_watson.AssistantV2(
    iam_apikey = 'xxx', # replace with API key
    version = '2019-02-28',
    url = 'https://gateway-syd.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api')

assistant_id = 'xxx' #Under Assistant Settings

# Create session.
session_id = service.create_session(
    assistant_id = assistant_id
).get_result()['session_id']

def Watson(b):
# Initialize with empty value to start the conversation.
    message_input = {
            'message_type:': 'text',
            'text': str(b)
            }

# Main input/output loop
    while message_input['text'] != 'quitt':

    # Send message to assistant.
        response = service.message(
                assistant_id,
                session_id,
                input = message_input
                ).get_result()

    # If an intent was detected, print it to the console.
        if response['output']['intents']:
            print('Detected intent: #' + response['output']['intents'][0]['intent'])

    # Print the output from dialog, if any. Supports only a single
    # text response.
        if response['output']['generic']:
            if response['output']['generic'][0]['response_type'] == 'text':
                return(response['output']['generic'][0]['text'])

    # Prompt for next round of input.
        message_input = {
                'text': str(b)
                }

# We're done, so we delete the session.
    service.delete_session(
            assistant_id = assistant_id,
            session_id = session_id
            )


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/sms", methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def incoming_sms():

    """Send a dynamic reply to an incoming text message"""
    #Get the message the user sent our Twilio number
    body = request.values.get('Body', None)
    b = str(body)
    b = b.lower()
    resp = MessagingResponse()


    r = Watson(b)


    resp.message(r)

   # response.append(r)
    return str(resp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Can you edit your post, re-paste the traceback and format it as code? It's unreadable like this.

Comment: Which GAE environment? What is your scaling config?

Comment: First, thank you @DanCornilescu for editing my formatting. I'll do better next time.

Comment: I'm using automatic scaling, instance class F1.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using? If you're using Twilio then the communication should all be via HTTP requests. It looks like something is going wrong with you Watson integration though. Basically, checking out the code might help us understand what is going on better.

Comment: @philnash I've uploaded my code. I'm quite new at this, but I'll look into whether all requests are via HTTP. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So, you have a `while` loop in there that potentially(?) doesn't end. If you're finding your server is running out of memory and that's what's causing the internal errors, then perhaps take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an exception from the `ibm_cloud_sdk_core` package. This could possibly be due to App Engine scaling up to multiple instances, but session IDs not being shared across instances. So instance A might have a session ID, but a subsequent request might go to instance B which does not have this session ID.

You should reach out to the library maintainers to understand how to either pool session IDs, or determine whether you have a valid session ID for a request before making the request to their API.

Comment: I think you're on to something here. I'll look into it.  Thanks!